# Use gpu to find good hashes

Tags: python, gpu

Currently I run a endless while loop to do some calculations and update a variable if it finds a better one

```
def findKey(i):
  while True:
     r = int.from_bytes(os.urandom(32), 'big')
     key = network.keys.private(secret_exponent=r)
     if isBetter(key, toUse):
       toUse = key
```

And I have used Threads for that

```
global toUse
toUse = None
for i in range(10):
  t = Thread(target = findKey, args=(i,))
  t.start()
```

I was wondering if GPUs could help here and how to use them?

Comment: That depends on the code that runs in `network.keys.private(secret_exponent=r)` , not the python code

Comment: Rather than going for GPUs, you should first look at using `multiprocessing`, since CPU-bound Python threads will compete against each other due to the GIL.

Comment: @AKX good to know will try thanks

Comment: Also, you'll probably want to try a faster random number generator; see e.g. the https://pypi.org/project/fastrand/ package.